# Compare two values using ´=?´ in Java

Tags: java, if-statement, arraylist

How can I compare two values without using IF. I know it´s possible to use `= ?` or something like this. For instance, let´s compare the size of two arraylists `c` and `t`. For this, I would like to use a code similar to:

```
boolean answ = ? c.size() = t.size();
```

Comment: why would you want to avoid `if`? It might shed some light on what you are really trying to achieve... Is it just for the purpose of assigning? [which is indeed a good reason to use the trinary operator...]

Comment: And compare how exactly?

Comment: boolean answ = (c.size() == t.size());

Comment: Thank you, I didn´t know the term ´ternary operator´, but this is exactly what I wanted to use. However, in my example I can simply write boolean answ = c.size() == t.size(), as alf and dkulkarni have suggested.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `boolean answ = c.size() == t.size();`

The ternary operator, `?`, is used to get *one of two* answers—you don't need it if you only need *one* boolean answer.

Answer (score 4):

If you need to use ? you have to write:

```
boolean answ = ( c.size() == t.size() ? true : false );
```

but this is much longer than writing

```
boolean answ = ( c.size() == t.size()  );
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
boolean answ = c.size() == t.size();
```

What you might remember is the short if else construct:

```
return c.size() == t.size() ? true : false;
```

Comment: the latter would not compile.

Answer (score 2):

This code will compare without using `if`:

```
boolean answ s= (c.size()==t.size()) ? true : false;
```

Comment: it is using if, it is just shortly written and the overhead is there, too. Why use the ternary operator if it works without?

Answer (score 1):

You mean the ternary operator?

```
result = expr1 ? expr2 : expr3;
```

If `expr1` evaluates to true then `result` is assigned the result of `expr2`, otherwise the result of `expr3`. So:

```
boolean answ = c.size() == t.size() ? true : false;
```

Answer (score 1):

It is called ternary or conditional operator:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation

Answer (score 0):

To compare values you usually use `==` and not `=` unless you are comparing non-primitive values (then you'd have to use the `equals` method if you appropriately override it in the class).

A single `=` is used for affectation, not to test equality.

Comment: The reference to `String` is misleading here: actually you'd like to use `equals()` for *all* non-primitive values. `String` is by no means special.